# Making free payments in a Django projects

Tags: django, payment, free

I am making a Django project for my final year of college. I also have a payment option in the project. But every payment gateway is charging some fees for processing transactions. I need some free payment option for my project, just a QR code for payment will also work. Can someone help me find a free payment option which I can easily get working on my Django project?

I have tried finding a way through RazorPay, Paytm, etc. but no where I found what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you want to make real transactions or just show that it works?

Comment: Just show it works(Even test payments will work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then register to any of the payment gateway e.g stripe and then use the test mode, they will provide you with a card number for success and another card(s) for error during payment and you can use those to validate the the payment gateway works and this is always free.

Processing real transactions is what is charged by payment gateways.

Comment: I registered to stripe and integrated it with my Django project. The test payments work fine. Thank You